# Выполнить запрос для каждого пользователя

Tags: postgresql

Имеется лишь одна таблица с ip-адресом пользователя и страницей, которую он посмотрел. Кусок таблицы для примера:

[image: Кусок таблицы для примера]

Как узнать, например, сколько страниц максимально посмотрел посетитель?
Получается, что нужно определить сколько страниц посмотрел каждый пользователь, и выбрать максимальное значение. Но я не понимаю, как определить это внутри базы данных сразу для всех пользователей, а не для какого-то одного, указанного через ip-адрес.

Comment: что Вам не понятно и что вызделали чтоб понять!?

Comment: @Yaroslav я понимаю как определить значение того, сколько страниц посетил какой-то конкретный пользователь: select count(*) from (select * from имя_таблицы where user_ip = "ip-адрес конкретного пользователя") t, но не знаю как сделать, чтобы не нужно было подставлять конкретное значение ip-адреса, а обработать сразу все случаи (каждого пользователя).

Comment: используйте `group by user_ip`. И кстати делать `select count(*) from (select * ...` нет особого смысла, count можно получать сразу из таблицы, без подзапроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По подсказке @Mike получилось что-то такое:

```sql
SELECT MAX(pages_count) FROM
(
    SELECT user_ip, COUNT(*) AS pages_count
    FROM info
    GROUP BY user_ip
) t
```